# Error create table sqllite (android)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

When I create new table like:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_AREAS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cs_area` (" +
"  `area_id` mediumint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"+
"  `areaname` varchar(40) NOT NULL,"+
"  PRIMARY KEY (`area_id`),"+
"  KEY `areaname` (`areaname`)"+
") DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;";
```

i got error :

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near
>   "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE
>   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cs_area` (  `area_id` mediumint(6) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,  `areaname` varchar(40) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY
>   (`area_id`),  KEY `areaname` (`areaname`)) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
>   AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

Maybe, anybody can help me ? Thanks

Comment: Is this a table in sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

change `AUTO_INCREMENT` to `autoincrement` and tell us about your result.

Comment: nothing change:
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "autoincrement": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cs_area` (  `area_id` mediumint(6) NOT NULL autoincrement,  `areaname` varchar(40) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`area_id`),  KEY `areaname` (`areaname`)) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

Comment: private static final String SQL_CREATE_AREAS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cs_area` (" +
"  `area_id` mediumint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"+
"  `areaname` varchar(40) NOT NULL,"+
"  PRIMARY KEY (`area_id`),"+
"  KEY `areaname` (`areaname`)"+
")";

Comment: change `mediumint(6) NOT NULL` to `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement`

Comment: `varchar(40) NOT NULL` to `TEXT` an add in your EditText(in your xml file) this `android:maxLength="40"`

Comment: `"  PRIMARY KEY (`area_id`),"+
"  KEY `areaname` (`areaname`) ` put this out

Comment: yeah, that's works. thank u, jamal!
but why ? and I just think, that it's nat a good practice use android:maxLength="40" just for db or not ?

Comment: your welcome :). we have here not a FULL DB like MYSQL for example, it is a "light version". that means that we cant use every commands here. 
`android:maxLength="40"` you have to put this in your activity xml file where you have your Edittext. Sorry for my english :D

Answer (score 0):

It's `AUTOINCREMENT` not `AUTO_INCREMENT`: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html